# Array or other solution

Tags: android

I have this code to generate a file,

```
et_nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre); // name file automatic
et_tienda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_tienda);  // Store Out
et_destino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestino); // Store In
et_contenido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_contenido); // Barcode

android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", new java.util.Date());
long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date curDateTime = new Date(msTime);

String t_origen=et_tienda.getText().toString();
String t_destino=et_destino.getText().toString();
et_nombre.setText("Traspaso_"+curDateTime+"  "+msTime);
```

---

```
public void Guardar(View view) {
    String nombre = et_nombre.getText().toString(); // EditText nombre fichero generado solo escritura desabilitada
    String letra_T = "T"; // valor fijo para cada línea del fichero
    String tienda = et_tienda.getText().toString();  // tienda origen  se repite en cada línea
    int tienda_num = Integer.parseInt(tienda);  // tienda origen formato int
    String tienda_destino = et_destino.getText().toString(); // tienda destino se repite en cada línea
    int tienda_des = Integer.parseInt(tienda_destino);  // tienda destino formato int
    String contenidos = et_contenido.getText().toString(); // código de barras escaneado uno por línea

    String prueba = String.format("%6d" , tienda_num );  // tienda origen con formato definido
    String destino = String.format("%6d" , tienda_des );  // tienda destino con formato definido
    String barras = String.format("%-25d" , new BigInteger(contenidos));  // código de barras con formato definido
    String unidad = "0000000001";  // unidad para cada lectura

    String contenido = letra_T + prueba +destino +barras +unidad;  // línea correcta

    try {
        File tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(this, tarjetaSD.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File rutaArchivo = new File(tarjetaSD.getPath(), nombre);
        OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo =new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo));
        //OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(nombre, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));
        crearArchivo.write(contenido);
        crearArchivo.flush();
        crearArchivo.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        et_nombre.setText("");
        et_contenido.setText("");
        et_tienda.setText("");
        et_destino.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

---

```
EditText et_contenido; //reading barcode  
EditText et_tienda; //Store out
EditText et_Destino; //Store In
```

---

```
Resulting file is correct  example  
txt_contenido : 99123456789
txt_tienda : 12
etDestino :  25
letra_T = "T"   fixed value.
unidad = "0000000001" fixed value.
```

---

```
T    12    2599123456789              0000000001
```

But I would like to read several barcodes in a row and save them in the same file and respecting the format by changing only the value of the barcode.
which option is correct create an array and a for   or  change the edittext to multiple lines and loop for
Thanks for the help

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking?

Comment: Now I get a file with a single row, the last one, and I want to read several like this

`T    12    2599123456789              0000000001`
`T    12    2599888888888              0000000001`
`T    12    2599652535682              0000000001`
`T    12    2599258147369              0000000001`
`T    12    2599597821463              0000000001`

Answer (score 0):

Create an array and after a lot of reading write it to a file would be good for performance than open the file and write to it for each barcode reading, but, sometime you would have to flush the content of the array to the file, you would need to have a trigger, a timer or anything else that could understand the right time to write to file, it is the "challenge". 
So write to file every single barcode reading is easier to implement, but depending on the quantity of barcodes reading you perform it could have a performance problem related to open/write/close the file every time.
You could, also, concatenate the barcodes in a string and after all reading write this string to the file.

Comment: If another test I have is to capture the barcodes in an edit Text mutiple line, but I have the problem when trying to add the variables at the beginning and end of each barcode and generate the file

Comment: Can't you just split the content of the edit text multi line?